# Handling expected vs operational errors with A+ Promises

Tags: javascript, bluebird, es6-promise

I've been using bluebird promises for a while now and one thing I really like about them is their implementation of a targetted 'catch' as well as the .error short hand for explicitly catching OperationalErrors.

This allows me to do things like:

```
var p = new Promise(/*stuff*/);
p.then(function(){ /* good */ })
.error(function(){ /* only handle expected operational cases */ });
.catch(function(){ /* if needed, handle unexpected errors, usually just crash */});
```

However in the promise spec, there is no ".error", the closest thing would look more like:

```
var p = new Promise(/*stuff*/);
p.then(function(){ /* good */ })
.catch(function(e){
        if (e instanceof ThingIExpect){
            //do something
        }else{
            throw e; //die
        }
});
```

But one of the benefits of the .error syntax is that by NOT using catch, code like this will just crash, which imho is what it *should* do:

```
"use strict";
var p = new Promise(function(f,r){
    a = 10; //Reference Error
    f(true);
});


p.then(function(val){
    console.log(val); //never gets hit - ReferenceError
}).error(function(e){
    console.log(e); //never gets hit - ReferenceError
});
```

Here my reference error just crashes. Using bluebird I never have to worry about a junior developer doing this as long as I lint, or code review for .catch being used only when needed.

```
"use strict";
var p = new Promise(function(f,r){
    a = 10; //Reference Error
    f(true);
});


p.then(function(val){
    console.log(val); //never gets hit - ReferenceError
}).catch(function(e){
   //attempt to handle ReferenceError instead of just crashing.
});
```

There is also no concept of OperationalError, a rejection is just type Error. So it is difficult to check explicitly for rejections vs other possible errors unless you always reject on your own custom types.

So with all of that said, finally the question:

What is the best way to approach operational vs expected errors when writing an application using native Promises or something that implement the A+ spec to the letter?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this is complicated.  If you have an error type you are "expecting" and wish to handle, can't you just check for that specific type of error in a `.catch()` and if you get any other kind of error in that handler, you treat it as an unknown, unexpected error?  Can't you just do that by checking the error type in `.catch()` or the second `.then()` handler?  Personally, I rarely find I need to code a different behavior for different types of errors.  There are some specific cases, but that's rare for me and I can handle it with an `if` statement.

Comment: You have to do that `instanceof` check everywhere, but you can extract it to a method. There is no clever way to do this with built in promises.

Comment: We're not in a traditional language. Promise chains will be shorter, and catch()'s will generally appear at the end of them. But your point stands. You can code innocently, use promises, and your code will fall over on error so long as you never write a catch. If you do write a catch in code that's likely to be chained, you need bear in mind that by so doing you're enabling the chain to continue. The only good reason for writing a catch in the middle of a chain is to recover from an error. You need to be rigorous in treating only the error you're targeting, and re-throwing any others.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rejecting with a custom error, consider moving "expected failures" into the success case. In other words, instead of:

```
var p = new promise(function (f, r) {
    var result = getResult();
    if (result > 5) { f(result); }
    else { r(new Error("result was too small")) }
});
```

Try:

```
var p = new promise(function (f, r) {
    var result = getResult();
    if (result > 5) { 
        f({success: true, result: result}); 
    }
    else { 
        f({success: false, reason: "result was too small"}); 
    }
});
```

Now you know that the error-case handler will only be called for *unexpected* failures, which is what you're interested in.

Another upside is that you're now modelling operational errors explicitely, and who ever's writing the fulfillment handler will be encouraged to think about handling the `success: false` case.